# PosExplorer.GetDevice() returns Always null in C#.net Windows form Application

Tags: c#, printing, point-of-sale, opos, pos-for-.net

I am working on Thermal Receipt Printer (ARP-990KE) for project where i tried below code for printing invoice but in code `GetDevice()` give me error **Value cannot be null.Parameter name: device**

```
       PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer(this);

       DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice("Generic/Text Only"); 
       return (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice);  //  Here it gives me null
```

Answer (score 1):

The GetDevice seems to be confused by `"Generic/Text Only"` you're passing it.

The `PosExplorer.GetDevice(String)` method (i.e. the one accepting single parameter) returns a default device for the given device class. The device class should be one of the constants from `DeviceType` class (`DeviceType.PosPrinter` in your case). This is what `GetDevice(String)` expects as its parameter:

```
DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter);
```

Please note, if you're going to use this method, make sure you've set up your printer as default (or there is no other devices of this type).

You may wish to consider using a more generic alternative. `PosExplorer.GetDevice(String, String)` accepts a device name in its second parameter so you're not bound to the default device only:

```
DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, <device name>);
```

The `<device name>` can be figured out using

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Point Of Service\posdm.exe" listdevices /type:PosPrinter
```